# Elixir split string with regex

Tags: regex, elixir

I have the following line, I need to split strings keeping separators

```
>>String.split("hello()", ~r{(?=\W)|(?=\d)(?<=\D)})
>>["hello","(",")"]
```

In that case is working correctly, but I need to add some changes and I don't know how to do it.

It must split the strings: "-a" "(b" etc, and it doesn't split them. So i need:

```
>>["-","a"]
```

It doesn't have to split strings with numbers "hello1". I need:

```
>>["hello1"]
```

Comment: Please indicate what separators the regex is supposed to split on.

Comment: Try `~r{(?<=\W)(?!^)}`

Comment: If your current pattern is working correctly, you might add another clause `(?=\W)|(?=\d)(?<=\D)|(?<=[^\w\s])(?=\w)` See https://regex101.com/r/nfxliu/1

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is to not use regular expressions at all as it can be easily done by pattern matching (if you do not need to handle Unicode):

```
defguard is_alnum(c) when c in ?a..?z or c in ?A..?Z or c in ?0..?9

def parse(string), do: do_parse(string, "", [])

defp do_parse("", "", tokens), do: Enum.reverse(tokens)
defp do_parse("", curr, tokens), do: Enum.reverse([curr | tokens])

defp do_parse(<<c, rest::binary>>, curr, tokens) when is_alnum(c) do
  do_parse(rest, curr <> <<c>>, tokens)
end

defp do_parse(<<c, rest::binary>>, "", tokens) do
  do_parse(rest, "", [<<c>> | tokens])
end

defp do_parse(<<c, rest::binary>>, curr, tokens) do
  do_parse(rest, "", [<<c>>, curr | tokens])
end
```

This explicitly states what you are looking for and how to get that data. Additional feature is that it will always be linear to the length of the parsed string.